# How do I unsubscribe from an observable?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

If I have something that looks like this:

```
  func foo() -> Observable<Foo> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
      // ...
    }
  }

  func bar() {
    foo().observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
      .subscribeNext {
        // ...
      }
      .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
  }
```

If I want to [unsubscribe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Subscription.html#unsubscribe()) from the observable later on in `bar`, how would I do that?

**Update**

I'm aware I can call `dispose`, but according to the [RxSwift docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#disposing):

> Note that you usually do not want to manually call dispose; this is only educational example. Calling dispose manually is usually a bad code smell.

So is `unsubscribe` just not implemented?  I've gone spelunking through the RxSwift code, and to the extent that I can understand what's going on, it doesn't look like the `Disposable` that is returned from the subscribe methods is ever anything with useful functionality (other than disposing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add the `Observable` returned by `foo` to `disposeBag`. It disposes the subscription when it's deallocated. 
You can "manually" release the `disposeBag` by calling

`disposeBag = nil`

somewhere in your class.

After question edit: You want to selectively unsubscribe from some Observables, probably when some conditions are met. You can use another `Observable` which represents these conditions and use `takeUntil` operator to cancel the subscription as needed.

```
//given that cancellingObservable sends `next` value when the subscription to `foo` is no longer needed

foo().observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
  .takeUntil(cancellingObservable)
  .subscribeNext {
    // ...
  }
  .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: Sorry, my simplified example only has one observable.  In reality I will have multiple tasks in flight that I am observing, and I will want to selectively unsubscribe from some.  If I free the dispose bag, they'll all get unsubscribed.  And I will need the dispose bag for its intended use later, too.  Furthermore, I'm aware I can call `dispose` but according to the docs this is a bad code smell.  See updated text in my questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your use case, `takeUntil` might be an equivalent of `unsubscribe`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Details

- Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a), iOS 13, Swift 5
- RxSwift v 5.0.1

### Solution

if you want to unsubscribe from observable you just need to reset `disposeBag`

```
// Way 1
private lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

//...
disposeBag = DisposeBag()
```

---

```
// Way 2
private lazy var disposeBag: DisposeBag? = DisposeBag()

//...
disposeBag = nil
```

### Full sample

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class Service {
    private lazy var publishSubject = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: count)
    private lazy var count = 0
    var counter: Observable<Int>  { publishSubject }
    func unsubscribeAll() { publishSubject.dispose() }
    func increaseCounter() {
        count += 1
        publishSubject.onNext(count)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var service = Service()
    private lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavigationBar()
        subscribeToObservables()
    }
}

// MARK: Work with subviews

extension ViewController {

    private func setupNavigationBar() {
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
        view.addSubview(navigationBar)
        navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        var barButtons = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        barButtons.append(createNavigationItemButton(title: "subscr.", action: #selector(subscribeButtonTapped)))
        barButtons.append(createNavigationItemButton(title: "unsubscr.", action: #selector(unsubscribeButtonTapped)))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = barButtons
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = createNavigationItemButton(title: "+", action: #selector(increaseCounterNavigationItemButtonTapped))
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
        self.navigationBar = navigationBar
    }

    private func createNavigationItemButton(title: String, action: Selector?) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        return UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .plain, target: self, action: action)
    }

}

// MARK: Work with observers

extension ViewController {
    private func subscribeToObservables() {
        service.counter.subscribe { [weak self] value in
            guard   let value = value.element,
                    let navigationItem = self?.navigationBar?.items?.first else { return }
            navigationItem.title = "Counter \(value)"
            print(value)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }

    private func unsubscribeFromObservables() { disposeBag = DisposeBag() }
}

// MARK: Button actions

extension ViewController {
    @objc func increaseCounterNavigationItemButtonTapped(_ source: UIBarButtonItem) { service.increaseCounter() }
    @objc func subscribeButtonTapped(_ source: UIBarButtonItem) { subscribeToObservables() }
    @objc func unsubscribeButtonTapped(_ source: UIBarButtonItem) { unsubscribeFromObservables() }
}
```

### Screenshot of the sample app

[image]

Comment: Have you read the question? "from an observable" != "from all observables"

Answer (score 1):

Since above answer focuses on unsubscribing to the specific or particular observable, I will talk about unsubscribing all the observable together correctly and efficiently.

How to **Subscribe**:

```
this.myVariable$.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(value => {
  // Do the thing you want to do after there is change in myVariable
});
```

How to **Unsubscribe**:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
  this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}
```

using the above `ngOnDestroy` you can unsubscribe from all the observable.

Answer (score 0):

You could just override the disposeBag with a fresh one. If you need other observables to stay alive, create multiple disposeBags. If you think about it this is what happens when a class get's deallocated → Its disposeBag gets deallocated, releasing all subscriptions that class had.

Example:

**Note:** The example just shows the principle, I don't know why you would ever build something specifically as I have below. That being said, it may be interesting for clearing cells with `prepareForReuse`, depending on your architecture.

```swift
class MyClass {

   var clearableDisposeBag = DisposeBag()
   let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

   let dependencies: Dependencies
   let myObservable: MyObservable

   var myOtherObservable: MyOtherObservable?

   init(dependencies: Dependencies) {
      self.dependencies = dependencies
      self.myObservable = dependencies
         .myObservable
         .subscribe(onNext: doSomething)
         .disposed(by: disposeBag)
   }

   private func doSomething() {/*...*/}

   private func doSomethingElse() {/*...*/}

   private func subscribeToChanges() {
      /// clear previous subscription
      clearableDisposeBag = DisposeBag()
      /// subscribe again
      myOtherObservable = dependencies
         .myOtherObservable
         .subscribe(onNext: doSomethingElse)
         .disposed(by: clearableDisposeBag)
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did was creating another `DisposeBag`

```
var tempBag = DisposeBag()

fun bar() {
    foo().subscribe().addDisposable(tempBag)
}
```

so when you want to dispose you can just do `tempBag = nil` when you want to release. while you still have another `DisposeBag` that keep other disposables alive.

Comment: That's not going to dispose the first `Disposable`.  You're only creating another completely new `Disposable`.

Comment: @solidcell my point is you can create another `DisposeBag` where you can release it by `tempBag = nil` whenever you want. While you still have another `DisposeBag` that keep other disposables.

Comment: I see what you mean.  However, your answer still doesn't show how you'd use it to unsubscribe, nor does it show that you'd be using `tempBag` *in addition* to another `DisposeBag`.